# Others can't see my Amazing Grace hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2019

I've earned the *Amazing Grace* hat on Stack Overflow. It appears on my profile and I positioned the hat on my avatar.

I do not "hate hats."

Why does the hat not show up for other users or visitors?

Or, does it show up for other users? I actually don't know; I can only confirm it *does not* show up for visitors, by logging out.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok, so (by design) visitors will not see hats and my had shows up to other users is what you're implying. Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: FWIW, I can see the hat on your avatar, and I have made no changes to the default configuration on my account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per this [Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159140/188189)

> users who choose to "love hats" will see the other users who love hats wearing headgear. Otherwise, anonymous, drive-by, logged-out, and hat-hating users will see no hats anywhere.

If you're not a Stack Overflow regular i.e. you're just browsing then you might not know why we're all dressed funny and you might get confused.

If your friends want to see you in your finery you'll have to get them to log in too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not a policy maker but "get confused" seems odd in this context. What might they do in response to that confusion? I feel the most likely response is just "..oh look, a funny hat is on that avatar."

Comment: They might wonder if this is the "real" Stack Overflow or whether we've been hacked somehow. Anonymous users likely just want answers rather than to join in our games.